# In pytest, how can I abort the fixture teardown?

Tags: python, pytest

Our pytest environment has a lot of fixtures (mostly `scope='function'` and `scope='module'`) that are doing something of the form:

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function')
def some_fixture():
    ... some object initialization ...
    yield some_object
    ... teardown ...
```

We use the teardown phase of the fixture (after the yield) to delete some resources created specifically for the test.

However, if a test is failing, I don't want the teardown to execute so we will have the resources still exist for further debugging.

For example, here is a common scenario that repeats in all of our testing framework:

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function')
def obj_fixture():
    obj = SomeObj.create()
    yield obj
    obj.delete()

def test_obj_some_field(obj_fixture):
    assert obj_fixture.some_field is True
```

In this case, if the condition in the `assert` is `True` I want the `obj.delete()` to execute.
However, if the test is failing, I want pytest to skip the `obj.delete()` and anything else after the `yield`.

Thank you.

**EDIT**
I want the process to be done without altering the fixture and the tests code, I prefer an automatic process instead of doing this refactor in our whole testing codebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an example in the [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#making-test-result-information-available-in-fixtures) about how to do this. The basic idea is that you need to capture this information in a hook function and add it to the test `item`, which is available on the test `request`, which is available to fixtures/tests via the `request` fixture.

For you, it would look something like this:

```py
# conftest.py

import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst = True, hookwrapper = True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    # execute all other hooks to obtain the report object
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()

    # set a report attribute for each phase of a call, which can
    # be "setup", "call", "teardown"

    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)
```

```py
# test_obj.py

import pytest


@pytest.fixture()
def obj(request):
    obj = 'obj'
    yield obj

    # setup succeeded, but the test itself ("call") failed
    if request.node.rep_setup.passed and request.node.rep_call.failed:
        print(' dont kill obj here')
    else:
        print(' kill obj here')


def test_obj(obj):
    assert obj == 'obj'
    assert False # force the test to fail
```

If you run this with `pytest -s` (to not let pytest capture output from fixtures), you'll see output like

```
foobar.py::test_obj FAILED dont kill obj here
```

which indicates that we're hitting the right branch of the conditional.

Comment: I actually implemented this but unfortunately, it's only a halfway to my solution. I ended up with the original question because I want to completely automate the solution - meaning, to not have the `if...else` clause, rather just to abort the code after the `yield` on a failed assertion.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that. If you need to do this in many places, you could wrap up the behavior in a "run a callback if the test succeed" function, and (inside the fixture) pass that function a callback that does the cleanup.

Comment: I will think about the solutions you presented, I agree that my initial goal was maybe a dead end, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Teardown is intended to be executed independently of whether a test passed or failed.

So I suggest to either write your teardown code such, that it is robust enough to be executed whether the test passed or failed or to add the cleanup to the end of your test, so that it will only be called if no preceding assert failed and if no exception occurred before

Comment: Our repository consists of thousands of tests that are looking somewhat like the example in the original post, I don't want to refactor all of the methods, I'm looking for an automatic solution (maybe with pytest hooks, but I'm not sure that's the right direction).

Answer (score 0):

Set a class-level flag to indicate pass/fail and check that in your teardown.  This is not tested, but should give you the idea::

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function')
def obj_fixture():
    obj = SomeObj.create()
    yield obj
    if this.passed:
      obj.delete()

def test_obj_some_field(obj_fixture):
    assert obj_fixture.some_field is True
    this.passed = True
```

Comment: Sorry for not being precise enough - I'm aiming for an automatic solution that does not require a refactor to all of the tests and fixtures. I edited the post. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I use a `Makefile` to execute `pytest` so had an additional tool at my disposal. I too needed the cleanup of fixtures to happen only on success. I added the cleanup as a second command to my `test` method in my `Makefile`.

```
clean:
    find . | grep -E "(__pycache__|\.pyc|\.pyo)" | xargs rm -rf
    -rm database.db  # the minus here allows this to fail quietly

database:
    python -m create_database

lint:
    black .
    flake8 .

test: clean lint database
    pytest -x -p no:warnings
    rm -rf tests/mock/fixture_dir
```